# Orphaned consumers in disconnected sockets

Tags: node.js, socket.io, rabbitmq, amqp

The stack uses Socket.io, redis and RabbitMQ for a messaging platform.
The problem

A queue to rabbit mq is created when a socket is connected, the consumer cancellation logic is present in on disconnect event. The problem is in a faulty internet setting the disconnect is fired first after the callback of queue creation is executed later thus an orphaned queue is created.

## Server code

```
io.on('connection', async function(socket){ 
      socket.on('initializationAcknowledged', function(){
           // Creating a queue on rabbit MQ in auto delete setting 
           // That is the queue will exists till a consumer is present 
           // We cancel the consumer in on disconnect event
           rabbitMQ.assertQueue('', {autoDelete: true, expires: 6000}, function(err, q) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error while asserting the consumer queue.');
                };

                // Bind the queue  
                consumer.bindQueue(q.queue, 'some exchange', socket.userID);

                // Creating the consumer to consume on the created queue
                consumer.consume(q.queue, function(msg) {

                }, {noAck: true}, function(err, obj) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('There was an errow while assigning a consumer ');
                    }
                    // Setting the consumer tag on the socket to cancel consumer.
                    socket.consumerTag = obj.consumerTag;
                });
            });
      })
      // This is to make sure we have initialized and a stable internet connection
      socket.emit('initialization')

      socket.on('disconnect', function(){
            // It fires the disconnet event before and finds the consumerTag as undefined hence does not cancel.
            if (socket.consumerTag != undefined) {
                consumer.cancel(socket.consumerTag, function(err, ok) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('Error while cancelling the consumer:', err);
                    }
                    if (ok) {
                        console.log('Consumer cancelled successfully', ok);
                    }
                });
            }
      });
})
```

## Client code

```
const socket = io.connect("some url")
socket.on('initialization', function(data){
       // This is to make sure we have a stable internet connection
        socket.emit('initializationAcknowledged');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you check for the internet connection using dns.lookup(url,callback);
if callback returns true, only then go for the disconnect method.